# Youtube and Vimeo Video integration php html

Tags: php, iframe, video, youtube, vimeo

I have a user forum where people can question and upload videos.

I want to integrate youtube and vimeo videos in my website.

Now if someone enters a url in the textarea i can simply check it for youtube or video video.
But if someone insterts a `iframe` embeded code how do i check it ?

```
$link  = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0AqnCSdkjQ0";

$domain =  get_domain($link);

if($domain == 'youtube.com'){

    preg_match(
        '/[\\?\\&]v=([^\\?\\&]+)/',
        $link,
        $matches
    );
    if(!empty($matches[1])){
        $YTsrc = $matches[1];
    }else{
        $YTsrc = $link;
    }
    echo '<iframe width="640" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$YTsrc.'"></iframe>';
}else if($domain == 'vimeo.com'){
    $video_id = (int) substr(parse_url($link, PHP_URL_PATH), 1);
    echo '<iframe width="640" height="480" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/'.$video_id.'?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>';
}

function get_domain($url)
{
  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
    return $regs['domain'];
  }
  return false;
}
```

If i have this 
`$link = '<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/108650530" width="500" height="212" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>'`;

then how do i get a appropriate `vimeo` video ?